# Gradle compile project failing with spring boot plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to understand why adding the Gradle 4.x Spring Boot plugin to a  Gradle dependency is causing my build to fail. Setup based on this [link](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/):

```
Project
  |--build.gradle //plugin here is fine
  |--settings.gradle
Dependency
  |--build.gradle //plugin here causes failure
  |--com.activemq.common //dependency I want to import
```

In Dependency/build.gradle if I just have:

```
//Dependency/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
```

> gradle build --> This works as expected

Now if I add the Spring Boot Plugin it fails:

```
//Dependency/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I get an error that it can't find a package that's under Dependency

> gradle build --> Application.java:5: error: package com.activemq.common does
>   not exist

I can just remove the plugin but the dependency is also Spring Boot so I would like to have it.

I tried doing gradle build --info, but didn't see anything useful. Also tried Gradle 5 but got different errors that I'm still investigating.
Can anyone explain why adding the plugin would cause this failure?

Comment: can you show the build.gradle

Comment: The goal of the spring boot plugin is to generate an executable jar file containing a spring boot application and all its dependencies. As far as I understand, Dependency is just a library that you want to use in your root project. So it should not apply the boot plugin. It should simply apply the java-library plugin. If you want to use the spring boot BOM to get the boot dependencies versions, then see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation

Comment: @JBNizet - that didn't seem to help. I'll probably just inline the library like it says here but then I have to copy that folder in each time which feels awkward. https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to fix 2 things

1. I could not use a typical gradle.build like above, but had to use a special "Spring Boot’s dependency management in isolation" version which uses "mavenBom" - this example worked for me https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module/blob/master/complete/library/build.gradle.
2. I also could not use a settings.gradle in the Project/Dependency folders, but rather needed to put a settings.gradle at the top level like this:
   https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module/blob/master/complete/settings.gradle

This didn't work:

```
Project
  |--settings.gradle
Dependency
  |--settings.gradle
```

This worked:

```
Project
  |
Dependency
  |
settings.gradle
```